# Android Robolectric Exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am facing a problem with Robolectric library. I am writing unit tests using Robolectric, it's working locally but when I merge my code, it crashes on pipeline(remotely).
I am using 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0.2'
It fails by only adding this line to my test class: `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`

And the exception is:

> FAILED
>      org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException
>           Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue: Robolectric was working fine locally, but once pushed to Jenkins the gradle task to execute the tests fails.

You can execute the gradle task to run the tests with `-i -d` flags to see more debug output.

```
./gradlew -i -d test
```

For me this revealed that Jenkins was unable to download Robolectric dependencies:

```
13:58:43  13:58:42.904 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.my.package.Test > my_test_case STANDARD_ERROR
13:58:43  13:58:42.904 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/9-robolectric-4913185-2/android-all-9-robolectric-4913185-2.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
```

I could solve it by telling gradle to use our corporate proxy when running on Jenkins. One way to achieve this would be to add the following to your gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http://proxy.host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http://proxy.host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
```

---- **EDIT** ----

Actually I found a cleaner solution for my use case then configuring a proxy: Robolectric offers a way to configure the repository it uses during runtime (see http://robolectric.org/configuring/). This way I was able to tell it to use our corporate repository.

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.url', 'https://local-mirror/repo'
      systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.id', 'local'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly, this is the issue. What is the version of Robolectric do you use?

Comment: At the moment I'm using `4.3-beta-1`, but it also worked with `4.2`. Also, I switched to Androidx test dependencies with `testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'`

Comment: OK, I switched to Androidx too, but I fixed the error by creating a custom RobolectricTestRunner. I will publish my answer for others

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was (`./gradlew -i -d testDebug` printed it):

```
Caused by:
org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
----------
1) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371
...
```

Robolectric tried to fetch a dependency from the remote repository, but it couldn't.

As the output suggests, I have:

1. Manually downloaded `org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371` jar from the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371).
2. Located it in `/home/user/jars`
3. Installed Maven on my machine: `sudo apt install maven`
4. Linked the jar with Robolectic: `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/user/jars/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.jar`

Now `./gradlew testDebug` works fine.

Also check [the issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5456) on Github, maybe there will be some more useful information for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Christian.D said, Robolectric tries to download dependencies from external repository, but we need that it uses internal one. Below the fix:

1) Create a custom RobolectricTestRunner:

```
public class CustomRobolectricRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

public CustomRobolectricRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
}

static {
    RoboSettings.setMavenRepositoryId("my-nexus");
    RoboSettings.setMavenRepositoryUrl("your_custom_url");
}
}
```

2) Annotate your test class:

```
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
```

Good coding!